# how can I use node-canvas in electronjs-17 on windows?

Tags: node.js, msbuild, electron-forge, node-canvas

I've installed all essentials for my windows to build application with electronjs.

versions:

- node -v v17.5.0
- npm -v 8.4.1

```
> My dependencies

  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "extract-zip": "^2.0.1",
    "nan": "^2.15.0",
    "node-canvas": "^2.9.0",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.17.0",
    "sha1": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.63",
    "electron": "17.0.0",
    "electron-rebuild": "^3.2.7"
  }
```

`

> Errors

Creating library D:\test-app-latest\node_modules\node-canvas\build\Release\canvas.lib and object D:\test-app-latest\node_modules\node-canvas\build\Release\canvas.expCanvas.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::shared_ptr __cdecl v8::ArrayBuffer::GetBackingStore(void)" (_*imp*?GetBackingStore@Arr
ayBuffer@v8@@QEAA?AV?$shared_ptr@VBackingStore@v8@@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl parsePNGArgs(class v8::Local,struct PngClosure &)" (?parsePNGArgs@@YAXV?$Local@VValue@v8@@@v
8@@AEAUPngClosure@@@Z) [D:\test-app-latest\node_modules\node-canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]
CanvasRenderingContext2d.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::shared_ptr __cdecl v8::ArrayBuffer::GetBackingStore(void)" (_*imp*?G
ptr@VBackingStore@v8@@@std@@XZ) [D:\test-app-latest\node_modules\node-canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]
⠋ Preparing native dependencies: 0 / 1ImageData.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::shared_ptr __cdecl v8::ArrayBuffer::GetBackingArrayBuffer@v8@@QEAA?AV?$shared_ptr@VBackingStore@v8@@@std@@XZ) [D:\test-app-latest\node_modules\node-canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]
✖ Preparing native dependencies: 0 / 1

An unhandled error has occurred inside Forge:
node-gyp failed to rebuild 'D:\test-app-latest\node_modules\node-canvas'.
For more information, rerun with the DEBUG environment variable set to "electron-rebuild".

Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1

Error: node-gyp failed to rebuild 'D:\test-app-latest\node_modules\node-canvas'.
For more information, rerun with the DEBUG environment variable set to "electron-rebuild".

Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1

```
at NodeGyp.rebuildModule (D:\test-app-latest\node_modules\electron-rebuild\src\module-type\node-gyp.ts:129:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at ModuleRebuilder.rebuildNodeGypModule (D:\test-app-latest\node_modules\electron-rebuild\src\module-rebuilder.ts:93:5)
at ModuleRebuilder.rebuild (D:\test-app-latest\node_modules\electron-rebuild\src\module-rebuilder.ts:129:8)
at Rebuilder.rebuildModuleAt (D:\test-app-latest\node_modules\electron-rebuild\src\rebuild.ts:203:9)
at Rebuilder.rebuild (D:\test-app-latest\node_modules\electron-rebuild\src\rebuild.ts:158:9)
at D:\test-app-latest\node_modules\@electron-forge\core\src\util\rebuild.ts:38:5
```

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

`

Answer (score 0):

You can't at the moment, look at this: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/29893

The Electron project has made the decision to switch to clang/libc++ for their Windows builds. The MSVC STL and libc++ are not compatible when it comes to the implementation of `std::shared_ptr` - which means that all object files that are meant to be linked together have to use the same runtime.

And currently `node-gyp` does not support clang on Windows.

Which means that many native Node.js addons are left out in the cold.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround (as of 22/04/24 - Electron 18) is to stick to the last Electron 12 release that's still using the old build environment/API-Combination on Windows for native dependencies like canvas:

```
yarn add --dev electron@12.X.X
```

Specifically for node-canvas:

If you're using electron-builder disable rebuilding of native dependencies via config and switch to electron-rebuild which works properly.

electron-builder doesn't work with node-canvas properly in that combination with Electron 12 (or at all). Whatever ...

It works with Electron 12 and electron-rebuild.

Theoretically from how I understand it might be possible that either one the API or the dependencies become compatible but that's already a few majors in and nothing happened yet.

So check back later if that's still needed.

Comment: Does anyone know if there has been any update to this? Is using Electron 12 still the only option to use node-canvas? If so, what a shame!